# Rails: get validation error key instead of i18n string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise

I'm developing a Ruby on Rails 4.1.0 app which has an API for a mobile client and a backend for another type of users. The API lets the mobile client register a user, but I might not get the correct data, so in that case I need to tell the mobile client where were the errors. I'm using devise 3.2.4 for user management. So, right now, if the mobile user wants to register and fails the validations, this is the JSON I return to the mobile client:

```
{"errors": [
  "email": ["is not valid"]
]}
```

As the mobile app will be multilanguage, the app developers asked me to return all errors with a key instead of a sentence, so I should return them something like:

```
{"errors": [
  "email": ["invalid"]
]}
```

But I can't find a way to do so easily. When I run `user.valid?`, the `user.errors` object is filled with the i18n  translation of validation errors, so I can't get their keys.

I tried creating an i18n backend (inheriting from `I18n::Backend::Simple` and overwriting the `translate` method), but I'm having problems with `default` options that I don't want to handle while sending devise confirmation emails, or reset password instructions emails.

So, I want to know the reason why my record is not valid, but without the i18n string, only the key. Any idea on how to get that?

Thank you!